# Посоветуйте литературу по праславянскому языку

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, учебники и книги по праславянскому языку.

Comment: Почитайте Мейе и воспользуйтесь Гуглом — ответ на ваш запрос лежит на поверхности: http://www.proto-slavic.ru/psl-books.html.